# SharePoint 2010 Installation Checklist

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Is there a SharePoint 2010 CheckList out there that ensures that you have all of the features installed that a general org would need to have installed?

Answer (score 3):

Some good links here

[10 Tips Troubleshooting Installations for SharePoint 2010 and SharePoint Foundation](http://www.sharepointjoel.com/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=0cd1a63d-183c-4fc2-8320-ba5369008acb&ID=280)

Including the official

[Technet - Hardware and software requirements (SharePoint Server 2010)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262485.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can review this blog about SP 2010 installation: http://dynamics.co.il